# "binascii.Error: Incorrect padding" when making an encrypted password

Tags: python, passwords

```py
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet

"""
def write_key():
    key = Fernet.generate_key()
    with open("key.key", "wb") as key_file:
        key.file.write(key)"""

def load_key():
    file = open("key.key", "rb")
    key = file.read()
    return key

m_pwd = input("what is the master password? ")
key = load_key() + m_pwd.encode() 
fer = Fernet(key)

def view():
    with open("passwords.txt", 'r', encoding = "utf-8") as f:
        for line in f.readlines():
            data = line.rstrip()
            user, passw = data.split("|")
            print ("User:", user, ", Password:", 
                    fer.decrypt(passw.encode()))

def add():
    name = input("Account Name: ")
    password = input("Password: ")
    with open("passwords.txt", 'a', encoding = "utf-8") as f:
        f.write(name + "|" + str(fer.encrypt(password.encode()) + "\n"))

while True:
    mode = input("would you like to add a new password or view existing ones (view, add), press q to quit? ").lower()
    if mode == "q":
        break

    elif mode == "view":
        view()
    elif mode == "add":
        add()
    else:
        print("invalid mode")
        continue
```

````
    fer = Fernet(key)
    key = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(key)
  File "C:\Users\samsw\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\base64.py", line 133, in urlsafe_b64decode
    return b64decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\samsw\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\base64.py", line 87, in b64decode
    return binascii.a2b_base64(s)
binascii.Error: Incorrect padding```
````

its raising a "binascii.Error" when I try to input anything to decrypt the file I'm decently new to Python, and I'm not sure why this keeps happening. If anyone has any suggestions (or even better is able to fix the code), please respond :)

Comment: Please show the full traceback

Comment: My bad! just added.

Answer (score 1):

Fernet's key must be a 32-byte base64 encoded key:

```
>>> key = b"a"*32  # 32 bytes
>>> import base64
>>> key = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(key)
>>> cryptography.fernet.Fernet(key)
<cryptography.fernet.Fernet object at 0x0000017300541750>
```

Your key is shorter or longer than it should be, and isn't encoded correctly.

---

EDIT: I've [fixed](https://github.com/pyca/cryptography/pull/6768) cryptography so the error will be clearer. Thanks for bringing it to our attention :-)